# How Do I Uninstall Unofficial Software On Fedora 17

Tags: fedora, uninstall

I would like to know how to uninstall unofficial software in Fedora 17 GNOME(by unoffical I mean like RPMs I got from the Internet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the rpm name

```
rpm -qa | grep -i <program name>
```

Remove the rpm

```
rpm -e <package name>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find out packages not in any configured repository by `package-cleanup --orphans` (this is in the `yum-utils` package, highly recommended). Given the package names, `yum erase list of packages here` will get rid of them.